# Bootstrap 4 vs firefox preload issue

Tags: css, firefox, bootstrap-4, preload

Dear front end developers facing a propblem with CSS preload in firefox > 74.0

with the following code

`<link rel='preload' as='style' onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'" 
id='font-awesome' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.5.0' type='text/css' media='all' />`

the same link attributes and tags been preloaded with bootstrap 3 in firefox 74 >

Answer (score 0):

For firefox it's need to be preload using javascript in here is the code :

```js
var DOMTokenListSupports = function (tokenList, token) {
    if (!tokenList || !tokenList.supports) {
        return
    }
    try {
        return tokenList.supports(token)
    } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof TypeError) {
            console.log("The DOMTokenList doesn't have a supported tokens list")
        } else {
            console.error("That shouldn't have happened")
        }
    }
};
var linkSupportsPreload = DOMTokenListSupports(document.createElement('link').relList, 'preload');
if (!linkSupportsPreload) {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var link = links[i];
        if (link.rel === 'preload' && link.getAttribute('as') === 'style') {
            link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet')
        }
    }
};
```